# Does all javascript calls work in Hybrid Android app?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am building a Hybrid Android app using HTML5 and JavaScript.

In my app, I would be requiring to make system related calls such as getting the system's date and time.

I was wondering as to whether such system related calls will work in Android? Will they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [WebView.addJavascriptInterface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)
   will allow you to inject an arbitrary Java object into the WebView.
2. JavaScript running on the WebView can then call methods of the Java object.
3. These methods then run Java code (possibly accessing Android API).
4. These methods may return data back to the JavaScript on the WebView.